# imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in [my php file]

Tags: php, filestream

Im having issue when a user uploads and to crop a JPEG file, it will be saved successfully.But while execute following code get some error.[Note:this code will work perfect on my localserver]

Code:

```
$reg1 = "select * from table where did='".$did."'";
$reg2 = mysqli_query($con,$reg1);
$reg3 = mysqli_fetch_array($reg2);
echo $reg3['image1'];

if($reg3["image1"]!="")
{
$image1="uploads/".$reg3['image1'];

}

    echo $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image1); 
    list($pwidth, $pheight) = getimagesize($image1);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 2, 2, 0, 0, 152, 152, $pwidth, $pheight);
```

That $image1 retrive the correct img file from db.But $image doesn't work.

> Error :
>   Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg[filename]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in[php file directory name]
>
> Warning: getimagesize():failed to open stream: No such file or directory in[php file directory name]
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in[php file directory name]

Comment: Is the **$image1** pointing to the correct file?

Comment: It sounds like something referred to folder destination permissions.

Comment: @arunrc:Ya Yes $image1 code is below $reg1 = "select * from drivers_image where did='".$did."'";
$reg2 = mysqli_query($con,$reg1);
$reg3 = mysqli_fetch_array($reg2);
echo $reg3['image1'];

if($reg3["image1"]!="")
{
//$img_test=$reg3['image1'];

$image1="uploads/".$reg3['image1'];

}

Comment: Edit your question. Do not write your codes in comments.

Comment: Why you echo $image?

Comment: just i would check..dont't bother about @arunrc

Comment: your errors shows, no filein directory. That means $image1 have no file or path is not proper. Please recheck both.

Comment: i already checked it..$image1 shows the image.But error came on imagecreatefromjpeg

Comment: The error is clear: `"uploads/".$reg3['image1']` is the wrong path to the image. Perhaps it's an issue with using **relative paths** and the working directory being different, or the path is plain wrong. Start by constructing an **absolute path** for starters: `__DIR__ . '/uploads/' . ...` (adjust as necessary, `echo` the path, make sure it exists).

Comment: @deceze i didn't understand your comment..shall i give the full path of image??? but in my local it will execute fine..

Comment: Just `uploads/...` is a **relative** path, relative to the current working directory. That's a rather wonky way to specify a path and may break depending on your working directory. Use an **absolute path**, like `/var/www/html/uploads/...`, or wherever your directory is.

Comment: $image1="/public_html/office/uploads/".$reg3['image1'];                               is it right or not??   This is my full path...but it seems same error@deceze

Comment: Not the URL. The *file path* on your harddisk! `C:\Users\blah\...`, or `/var/www/html/...` or whatever.

Comment: i got exact error..if i give path directly to $image1 work perfectly..but if i get file name from db i got error..  $test=$reg3['image1'];
$test1="Desert.jpg"; $image1="uploads/".$test;  here $test1 is work fine..$test not be work

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolve my error.

While inserting image name in db extra space will add automatically. After edit Now it work properly.

Thanks for your response friends..